# Configure pgadmin4 to use Azure AD Oauth2 in openshift cluster

Tags: azure-active-directory, openshift, pgadmin-4

I wants to enable oauth2 authentication in pgadmin4 I have  followed https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/how-configure-oauth-20-pgadmin-4 to configure the azure oauth2 in openshift

I am not able to see the oauth2 login button
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: pgadmin-config
data:
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['oauth2']

```
OAUTH2_CONFIG = [
    {
        'OAUTH2_NAME': 'azure',
        'OAUTH2_DISPLAY_NAME': 'AzureActiveDirectory',
        'OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID': 'xxxxxx',
        'OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET': 'xxxxxx',
        'OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token'
        'OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_URL': "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        'OAUTH2_API_BASE_URL': 'domainname/oauth2/authorize',
        'OAUTH2_USERINFO_ENDPOINT': 'userinfo',
        'OAUTH2_SCOPE': 'openid email profile',
        'OAUTH2_ICON': 'azure',
        'OAUTH2_BUTTON_COLOR': '#E24329',
    }
]
OAUTH2_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
```

I have added my group in rolebinding group
Please let me know if i miss anything

I tried to set the azure ad authentication in pgadmin4 in openshift cluster
i am not able to see oauth2 button